# How to create workspace in TFS

Tags: tfs

I followed this way.

```
To create a workspace to manage your source-controlled files

   1.

      From the File menu, select Source Control, and then click Workspaces.
   2.

      In the Manage Workspaces dialog box, click Add.
   3.

      Type a descriptive name in the Name box, enter a comment describing the new workspace in the Comment box, and provide alternative Owner and Computer name values, as necessary.
   4.

      Under Working Folders, in the Source Control Folder box, click the text box and then the ellipsis (…).
   5.

      In the Browse for Folder dialog box, select a server folder, and then click OK.
   6.

      Under Working Folders, in the Local Folder box, click the text box, and then click the ellipsis (…).
   7.

      In the Browse for Folder dialog box, select a folder on your computer, and then click OK.
   8.

      In the Add Workspace dialog box, click OK to create the workspace.
   9.

      In the Manage Workspaces dialog box, click Close.
```

When I click OK button it should get all the folder from TFS to my Local machine? but its not doing that after clicking ok and Close nothing is happening and my local folder does not contain this files too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just creating the workspace won't get you the latest version.  Go to the "Source Control" section of a project in the "Team Explorer" tab.

Once you're in the source control view, you can right click any folder in source control, right click on it, and click "Get Latest Version".

Alternatively, there should be an "Open from source control" option in your File > Source Control menu if you need to open and get a particular solution file.

Comment: Plus choose the correct workspace from the drop down in the "Source Control View"

Answer (score 2):

Creating a Workspace in TFS doesn't pull any files out of Source Control. It just gives you an environment to manage all your Projects.

To pull down the source code, you still have to find the root folder for the Project you want, right click, and 'Get Latest...'

At that point, you'll be prompted to bind that project to a local directory on your machine where the source code will live.